# Guava - Getting the same value with multiple keys

Tags: java, guava

Say you have these methods in a service

```
ValueDto getValue(Key1 key1){}
ValueDto getValue(Key2 key1){}

class ValueDto{
   private Key1 key1;
   private Key2 key2;
   // Some other info
}
```

So we have pairs of Key1, Key2 that will give back the same ValueDto.

Whenever I use one of the methods, I want to cache the ValueDto with Key1 and Key2, to avoid having to do an expensive lookup with the other key when I really already know the answer from the lookup on the first key.

I'm looking to use Guava for this. I can surely find a way to do it by having two instances of LoadingCache and saving in both caches whenever I get a ValueDto.

But is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can make Key1 and Key2 generate the same hash code somehow?

Comment: @Simon a HashMap doesn't use the hashCode to compare keys. it uses equals(). hashCode() is only used to drastically reduce the number of potentially equal keys.

Comment: Since the value contains the keys, you can write a simple indexing layer on top. Have a function extract the keys, maintain a map<Kn, K1>, and cache<K1, V>. You can use lock striping for improved consistency between the data structures.